# git find missing code?

Tags: git

I made a bugfix and after a few days it disappeared. I don't see it in the branch and doing git log path/to/file doesn't show my changes (are there flags i need for code on different branches?).

How do I ask git what happened to my source if i know the file or date i edited? It could have been ignored/remove due to conflict or something strange. I'm just wondering where it went. Its a 3 line fix and I easily redid it

Comment: If you don't see any trace of your changes in the log, I would say you did something wrong (no push, reset or ...) localy

Comment: As long as he used `git commit` and not yet `git gc`, he should be able to get his stuff back (See `git reflog`.). That's the beauty of git, once you come to terms with this swiss army knife of a version control system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When everything else fails, you can always try looking at `git reflog`.

You can look at it as a safety net build into git.  It keeps track of all references you checked out or committed in git.

Just type `git reflog` and see if you can find a reference which contains your change.  With `git show <hash of reference>` you can get more information about a reference or open the hash with your favorit git gui.

More info about git-reflog:

- http://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html
- http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html

Good luck

Comment: Is there a way to search it? I have 400 reflogs and no idea what branch it was in

Comment: Like the man page says you can select your references.
For example `git reflog show master@{one.week.ago}`, show where the master branch was one week ago.